Is it possible to generate a summary table of another table?
The title may be vague, mostly because I can't really summarize this in a single sentence. I want to automatically fill a table based on the values in another table, but summed per name.
For example, if I had this table:



Name
Value




John
10


Jeff
23


John
3



I'd want to summarize this to just



Name
Value




John
13


Jeff
23



I can not use the entire column since it's in a table, so the top row is the name of the column in the table.

You just need QUERY() function. Try-
=QUERY(A:B,"select A, sum(B) where A is not null group by A",1)



I copied it, changed the A and B to the right columns, but it's giving me a formula parse error. Could it be because it's in a table in my sheet? The number in question is also converted to value, I don't think this should make a difference, but I can't see much difference between just a new sheet and mine other than the two I pointed out.

@WickedGrinn Can you show a screenshot? Also, due to language and regional settings you may need to use semicolon instead of comma. Try =QUERY(A:B;"select A; sum(B) where A is not null group by A";1) 

I recreated your exact screenshot in a separate page to test if that would work, but it still gives me the formula parse error

Aha, thank you, it needed a ; on the first and last comma indeed.
It works now.

Try this approach.
=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(A2:A), SUMIF(A2:A, UNIQUE(A2:A), B2:B)})

Sample Output


Better use MAP() or BYROW() function to make the formula as spill array.
